# Throwing errors while changing Ui design

Tags: c#

I have a Datagrid , 2 textBoxes and 4 buttons whenever I  change positions or add a new controls  , It gives errors form my grid variable saying it is not in current context  . I am  creating a window Application and using WinForms. I dont use any threads to Design

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ASP MVC?

Comment: Do you use multi-threading/another thread to arrange the positions?

Comment: No Threads to arrange the position

Comment: Can we see a code snippet? What events are you hooking into to change the positions or add controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be running into a pretty common issue. ..

The designer will execute any code found in the constructor and, if IIRC, the Load event.

Simple way to do this without rearranging all your code to guard any code that isn't purely (and I mean *purely*) layout code with a check to the form or control's DesignMode property...

```
if(!DesignMode)
{
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Scoregraphic asks are you performing this manipulation within a separate thread?